# Grub error on Ubuntu 16.04 installation: "grub-efi-amd64-signed failed" after windows installed on just one partition

Tags: grub2, boot-repair

First I installed Windows on just one partition (no others were created) following [one partition windows installation](https://superuser.com/questions/494684/is-it-possible-to-install-windows-8-in-only-one-partition), because I wanted to maximize the number of possible primary partitions.

When I installed ubuntu I got:

```
grub-efi-amd64-signed failed installation /target/
```

So grub failed to install.

On all installations I used lagacy support enabled on UEFI mode on a HP laptop.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Ubuntu bootable USB I used *boot repair*, then Ubuntu appeared as an option.

I entered on ubuntu and used *boot repair* again, then grub identified Windows